# Affine Encrypted String "8YM8FlYPiiMl.YP[eYWP[P[P." Unknown key

Tags: python, encryption

I am trying to decry-pt this  string encrypted via affine encryption. I could use a bit of help checking my work. It was encrypted using % 95 length ASCII alphabet. I realize this means there are only 6840 possible keys as there are only 72 possible co-primes of 95. Meaning 72 * 95 = 6840.
So I then wrote the python code below to check these keys, But all  the results still seem to be gibberish. Is the string encoded actually gibberish? or did I do something incorrectly? Thanks for taking the time to look over my work!

```
def chars_to_nums(c):
    nums = []
    for i in c:
        nums.append(ord(i) - 32)
    return nums


def nums_to_chars(n):
    chars = ""
    for i in n:
        chars = chars + chr(i + 32)
    return chars


def gcd(a, b):
    # Provide the correct implementation
    if a < b:
        x = b
        y = a
    else:
        x = a
        y = b
    while y != 0:
        r = x % y
        x = y
        y = r
    return x


def extended_euclid(a, b):
    num1 = a
    num2 = b
    gDiv = gcd(a, b)  # Find gcd using basic Euclid's Algorithm
    y, lastCoeffY = 1, 0  # y and previous coeffy
    x, lastCoeffX = 0, 1  # x and previous coeffx
    while num1 != 0:
        quo = num2 / num1
        remain = num2 % num1
        currentCoeffX = x - lastCoeffX * quo
        currentCoeffY = y - lastCoeffY * quo
        currentCoeffY,lastCoeffX, lastCoeffY,x,y
        num2, num1 = num1, remain
        x, y = lastCoeffX, lastCoeffY
        lastCoeffX, lastCoeffY = currentCoeffX, currentCoeffY
    return gDiv, [(y, b), (x, a)]

def inverse(n, m):
    # Provide the correct implementation
    if n > m:
        exp = extended_euclid(n, m)
    else:
        exp = extended_euclid(m, n)
    if  exp[0] == 1:
        return exp[1][0][0]
    else:
        return None

def affine_decode(ciphertext, a, b, m):
    inv = inverse(a, m)
    ciphertext = chars_to_nums(ciphertext)
    plaintext = []
    for i in ciphertext:
        p =  inv * (i - b) % m
        plaintext.append(p)
    return nums_to_chars(plaintext)

print affine_decode("2|NNc", 7, 23, 95)

#Brute Force decryption of "8YM8FlYPiiMl.YP[eYWP[P[P." unknown key
primelist = []
for i in range(95):
    if gcd(i,95) == 1:
        primelist.append(i)

for i in range(1,95):
   for j in primelist
       print affine_decode("8YM8FlYPiiMl.YP[eYWP[P[P.", j, i, 95)
```

## ciphertext = "8YM8FlYPiiMl.YP[eYWP[P[P."

## _plaintext = ""

Comment: Without the source code to `affine_decode()`, it's impossible for anybody to tell what your program is actually doing, or make any attempt to fix it.

Comment: I added it, but truthfully it is not needed to answer the question, one can assume affine decode is implemented correctly, as the issue not one of code correctness in regards to decode. As the decode I used  works just fine. I was more concerned if my cracking approach and math behind the encryption was correct as if it is the string is not actual text it is gibberish. Which again  is the nature of my question "8YM8FlYPiiMl.YP[eYWP[P[P." is this string gibberish once decoded?

Comment: So, you seriously think it's reasonable to ask everyone who might be interested in answering your question to reimplement the function if they want to examine the problem for themselves???  You didn't actually improve anything by adding the code that you did, because there's still several references to undefined functions.

Comment: No i just didnt think it was necessary to answer the question conceptually regarding the encryption. I can add it, but you seem awfully mad about it. Maybe you should relax a bit? If you dont want to help you dont have to ya know?

Comment: Why do you think `m = 95`? It's not.

Comment: What else would it be?

Comment: It is not mod 26.